# ¿Porque al cargar un dataframe en spark me aparece toda la tabla en null?

Tags: csv, scala, apache-spark

Estoy utilizando Apache Spark 2.3.0 pero al querer cargar el csv y luego mostrar sus datos con df.show aparece toda la table en null y no entiendo porque si el archivo si contiene los datos

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("Rank",StringType,true),StructField("Grade", StringType, true),StructField("Channelname",StringType,true),StructField("Video Uploads",IntegerType,true), StructField("Suscribers",IntegerType,true),StructField("Videoviews",IntegerType,true)))

val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").schema(schema).load("33.csv")
```

[image: tacla con valores null]

[image: archivo csv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado a despecificar el delimitador:

```
.option("sep", ",")
```

de tal forma que quede

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("sep", ",").schema(schema).load("33.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes Spark context te recomiendo usar:

```
val df = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true") //first line in file has headers
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .option("delimiter", "\t") // aqui puedes delimitar por cualquier ocurrencia "-", "," , ";"
      .load("pathCSV.csv")

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
```